# how to get the values from soap response in android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

the following xml tag for webservice response ,i dont know how to parse it..help me..

```
<NewDataSet>
            <JOBLIST>
            <CSIDNO>CS13224</CSIDNO>
            <PName>Selva</PName>
            <HouseID>G 34</HouseID>
            <NAME>Dilipan</NAME>
            <Address>Coimbatore</Address>
            </JOBLIST>
            <JOBLIST>
            <CSIDNO>CS13224</CSIDNO>
            <PName>Selva</PName>
            <HouseID>G 35</HouseID>
            <NAME>Kanrupannan</NAME>
            <Address>Coimbatore</Address>
            </JOBLIST>
            </NewDataSet>
```

i am using the following java code .....

```
for(int i=0;i<result.getPropertyCount();i++)
        {
            SoapObject ob=(SoapObject)result.getProperty(i);
            homeid[i]=String.valueOf(ob.getProperty("HouseID"));
            namearr[i]=String.valueOf(ob.getProperty("NAME"));
            address[i]=String.valueOf(ob.getProperty("Address"));
            csidno[i]=String.valueOf(ob.getProperty("CSIDNO"));


        }
```

how to get the values form xml tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple you have to get the respose as a string and use pattern matches to extract the detail you needed>Please see this post hope it helps you and you understand it.

```
String r = NameArray.columncount("userid", limitstart, loadNumber,loggername);
String temp = r.replaceAll(";\\s", ",").replaceAll("string=", " ")
.replace("anyType{", "").replace(",}", "");
enter code here
```

check this link for step by step instruction
http://amalan008.blog.com/2013/02/07/how-to-process-an-array-returned-by-a-wsdl-android/

Answer (score 2):

Why using Soap there are different kinds of parsing methods you can use one of them. Parsing methods are SAXParser, Json parser, DOM parser, XML pull parser. In yourt situation SAX parser will be good to parse. see [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example) and [this](http://androidtutorials60.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using.html)  tutorial. It will help you in parsing the xml you are receiving. Let me know if they helps you